# Please may someone tell me what this symbol means?

Tags: translation

[image]

Hello!

I was wondering whether this symbol meant anything? I tried to search on Google and even used the image search on Google translate but nothing came back.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems like '立' (stand; establish)

Answer (score 2):

This is a character “立”。

The basic meaning of "立" is "standing straight". However, since the picture you put is a tattoo, it usually has a deeper meaning.

The "立" in a tattoo can be understood as "顶天立地" which means when a person stands, his head reaches the sky and his feet step on the ground. With a deeper meaning, a person can withstand all kinds of difficulties and disasters and do their best to solve them, and the people around him are therefore safe.

Comment: 这是一个字 —— 立。“立”的基本含义是“笔直地站着”。不过，由于你放的图片是纹身，所以通常具有更深的含义。纹身中的“立”可以理解为“顶天立地”；直意为一个人站着的时候可以头顶着天，脚踏着地；表示一个人能扛得住各种各样的困难和灾难并竭尽全力解决它，而他周围的人因此而有安全感。